# Read txt file to array + increment variable on click to access next array element: PHP or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am reading a short text file on server into a PHP variable (`$data`), and first accessing the first 2 items in the array to display them.

Then when the user clicks one of the items (which also sends form data) I want to increment the PHP variable that specifies the array item (`$counter`).

Reading from the file seems to be easiest to do with PHP, but incrementing at click seems easier with Javascript - and I can't figure out a good way to forge the two. What is the best way to solve this? I am fairly new to both languages.

The php/html code for reading from file (working):

```
<?php
function getData($subtest_nr) {
    $data = file("subtests/$subtest_nr.txt");
    return $data;
}

$subtest_nr = "7";
$counter = 0;
$data = getData($subtest_nr); ?>

<form id="myform" method="post">
    <div class="four_images">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.11" id="alt1" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt1"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter]; ?>"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.12" id="alt2" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt2"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+1] ?>"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

A quick attempt at incrementing variable in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var counter = 0;
    $("img").click(function(){
        counter++;
        $("p").text(counter);
    });
});
```

So my question is if I should aim for either only PHP or Javascript/jQuery for both functionalities or if there is a way for me to merge the two?

Comment: What about a php file that takes 2 parameters - `firstItem` and `numItems`? The javascript knows where you're up to and then makes a request to the php file e.g `theFile.php?firstItem=0&numItems=2`

Comment: I couldn't say... Am too much of a beginner at JS & PHP. Could try, but I'd need more assistance.

Comment: Yeah, it's a good way. All of your state information is maintained client-side, with the backend just providing whatever data is requested. You just need to work out how to access items in your text file by index. This will involve skipping over n items in your text file when item n is requested. Without knowing what the input data looks like, obviously I can offer nothing here.

Comment: My input data is a txt file on the server in same folder as php and js files, with each item (either a file name or single word) on a separate line. So fetching the text on row n is all that is needed, but this doesn't seem too easy to me with javascript.

Comment: ah, in that case it's a piece of cake. You need to be able to skip lines. Have a look in the php docs for the function `fgets` - it will retrieve a single line of text from a file. In your case, you need to get `M` items, starting at item `N`. So, you call `fgets` `N` times and throw-away the results. You then call it `M` times, accumulating the results of each line-read. The whole idea is you do it from PHP and return _only_ the data that you actually want.

Comment: I've tried `fgets` earlier, but the problem for me is then how to get the next 2 items (images) in the text file to be displayed when I click one of the images. I could use some tangible coding to get how this is done with your solution. Don't know how to use parameters to the php file.

Comment: I'll put something together after dinner. Part of the solution is AJAX - when the user does something in the page that necessitates more data, the javascript fires of an AJAX request for the desired items. The PHP then provides them, the javascript catches this reply before dealing with the returned data. Its a very useful technique, and quite simple once you've the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments, here's an approach that combines the font-end and the back-end into a single file.

The file makes use of the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] variable to find the name of the file that's executing. We use this to write the correct name of the backend php file to request into the javascript - this has the effect of allowing us to name the single-file solution anything we want and not worry about updating a hard-coded url somewhere in the source. (got a sore head yet? :p )

### index.php

```
<?php
    if ( isset($_GET['firstItem']) && isset($_GET['numItems']) )
    {
        $firstItem = $_GET['firstItem'];
        $numItems = $_GET['numItems'];

        // should do error checking here

        $subtestNumber = 7;
        $filename = sprintf("subtests/%d.txt", $subtestNumber);

        // dummy, used for testing
        $filename = 'sampleInput.txt';

        $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "rt");

        for ($numLinesToSkip=0; $numLinesToSkip<$firstItem; $numLinesToSkip++)
            fgets($fileHandle);

        $results = array();
        for ($itemCount=0; $itemCount<$numItems; $itemCount++)
        {
            $curLine = fgets($fileHandle);
            //
            // you may wish to remove the trailing new-line character here
            //
            array_push($results, $curLine);
        }
        fclose($fileHandle);

        echo json_encode($results);
        die;                            // stop execution now - dont output the html below
    }
?><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

function ajaxGet(url, onLoad, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) onLoad(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function() {error.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClicked);
}

function onGoBtnClicked(evt)
{
    var firstIndex = byId('firstRecordInput').value;
    var numItems = byId('numRecordsInput').value;

    // we want to request data from this same file, so get php to print it into the javascript source
    var filename = '<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>';

    // construct the url from the filename and the (GET) parameters we'd like to pass to the php
    var url = filename + '?firstItem=' + firstIndex + '&numItems=' + numItems;

    // ask for it, fire the onDataReceived function with the XMLHttpRequest object as the only input
    ajaxGet(url, onDataReceived, function(){alert('ajax failed! :(');} )
}

/*
    ------------------------------------------------------------
     format of html the onDataReceived function needs to create
     - .four_images div just once for the whole response
     - .flex-item once for each item returned
    ------------------------------------------------------------
    <div class="four_images">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.11" id="alt1" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt1"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter]; ?>"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.12" id="alt2" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt2"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+1] ?>"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
*/
function onDataReceived(ajax)
{
    // get the raw data - it'll be a string something like `["file1.txt\n","file2.swf\n"]`
    var rawData = ajax.response;
    // parse it and turn it from a string into some javascript objects. 
    // this has same the effect as typing the following into your source-code
    //
    //  var parsedData = [ "file1.txt\n", "file2.swf\n" ];
    //
    //  except, you can do it with unknown data. BUT: we must know the *format*
    //  of the data so we know what to do with it. We happen to know that
    //  the data will be an array
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

    // make the outer wrapper - refer above for the structure of the created HTML
    // this wrapper needs to exist so the makeItem function can append content
    // to it in the forEach call
    var div = newEl('div');
    div.className = 'four_images';

    // for each of the items in the parsedData array, call the makeItem function - once this forEach call is done,
    // we have the contents of the form all sitting in the [div] element - the makeItem function is inside this onDataReceived function
    // so that it can 'see' the [div] variable in order to append each item to it.
    forEach(parsedData, makeItem);

    // show the results
    byId('myForm').innerHTML = '';
    byId('myForm').appendChild(div);

    // this function has now finished executing. the makeItem function exists here (unfortunately) so that
    // the [div] element remains in scope.

    // called with the current element in the collection as dataItem, it's index in the collection as index and the collection itself as arrayOfItems
    //  we're making use of the item's index to correctly set the id of the radio-button and then to make the label refer to it (which it doesn't actually
    //  need to do in this case, since the label element contains the input)
    //  another use of index is to place a comma between items i.e "1,2,3,4,5,6" - there are two approaches. The naive one is to place a comma after each
    // item except the last one. To do this - we need to know how many items there are in total - sometimes this is very expensive to compute.
    // the other approach, is to put a comma _before_ all items except the first one.
    function makeItem(dataItem, index, arrayOfItems)
    {
        var itemDiv = newEl('div');                 
        itemDiv.className = 'flex-item';            

        var input = newEl('input');                 
        input.type = 'radio';                       
        input.name = 'image';                       
        input.value = 'putSomethingUsefulHere';     // **** the example had 7.11 and 7.12 here - I've no idea how they were determined ***

        input.id = "alt" + (index+1);               
        input.className = 'hidden';

        var label = newEl('label');
        label.for = 'alt' + (index+1);

        var img = newEl('img');
        img.src = 'images/' + dataItem;
        label.appendChild(img);

        itemDiv.appendChild(input);
        itemDiv.appendChild(label);

        div.appendChild(itemDiv);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.panel
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #eef;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='panel'>
        <label>Index of first record: <input type='number' id='firstRecordInput' value='0'/></label><br>
        <label>Number of records: <input type='number' id='numRecordsInput' value='2'/></label>
        <hr>
        <div style='text-align: center'><button id='goBtn'>Retrieve records</button></div>
        <hr>
        <form id='myForm'>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, definitely sore head. ;) I'm just wondering about the javascript creating everything anew for each click.. Would it be better (more efficient), say, to have all the div elements, radio buttons and labels in the html to start with, but just change/add the image according to the filename found in the txt-file?

Comment: :chuckles: sorry! I reckon that sounds like a good plan. No idea about timing (you can test it yourself. performance.now() or something like that gets a timestamp I think) - but it would certainly make the code easier to read and understand if you went about it that way. Why not have a go at 'clambering over the mountain' (as I like to think of solving programming problems) like that, if you've the time, I'm sure you could do worse things with it than try a different approach.

Comment: I have another question about the code - why do I want the PHP to die and not execute the HTML code? I notice things don't work when I remove it, but I don't know why. (Thing is, I'm now wanting to add PHP code to echo data posted with JS about which image has been clicked and I can't figure out where to put it.)

Comment: Simply because the `die` statement is where the PHP file would end, if it wasn't 'glued-together' with the HTML into a single file. Recall my first example, with separate HTML and PHP files. Perhaps modifying that would be a better place to start before you get into the clusterf***k that can be combined files like this. As it stands, from the info you've left, I wouldn't have a clue either - there are no click handlers on the images, so I've no idea what you're doing there that requires php. Seems to me like a good time to ask a fresh question. ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks! Will try changing back to separate files! Yes, maybe the time has come for yet another question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rough example, sans error checking. I don't jQuery, so you'll need to convert this to make use of jQuery's ajax method. Can't tell what you're trying to achieve with each image click either, so you can edit that back in.

My primary aim, was to show a means by which the front-end can maintain state information and can use this to request to desired info from a (dumb) backend.

### sampleInput.txt

```
file1.txt
file2.swf
file1.pdf
file1.exe
file1.asm
```

### getItems.php

```
<?php
    $firstItem = $_GET['firstItem'];
    $numItems = $_GET['numItems'];

    // should do error checking here

    $subtestNumber = 7;
    $filename = sprintf("subtests/%d.txt", $subtestNumber);

    // dummy, used for testing
    $filename = 'sampleInput.txt';

    $fileHandle = fopen($filename, "rt");

    for ($numLinesToSkip=0; $numLinesToSkip<$firstItem; $numLinesToSkip++)
        fgets($fileHandle);

    $results = array();
    for ($itemCount=0; $itemCount<$numItems; $itemCount++)
    {
        $curLine = fgets($fileHandle);
        //
        // you may wish to remove the trailing new-line character here
        //
        array_push($results, $curLine);
    }
    fclose($fileHandle);

    echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

### getStuff.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
function newEl(tag){return document.createElement(tag)}
function byId(id){return document.getElementById(id)}

// useful for HtmlCollection, NodeList, String types
function forEach(array, callback, scope){for (var i=0,n=array.length; i<n; i++)callback.call(scope, array[i], i, array);} // passes back stuff we need

function ajaxGet(url, onLoad, onError)
{
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) onLoad(this);}
    ajax.onerror = function() {error.log("ajax request failed to: "+url);onError(this);}
    ajax.open("GET", url, true);
    ajax.send();
}

/////////////////////

window.addEventListener('load', onDocLoaded, false);

function onDocLoaded(evt)
{
    byId('goBtn').addEventListener('click', onGoBtnClicked);
}

function onGoBtnClicked(evt)
{
    var firstIndex = byId('firstRecordInput').value;
    var numItems = byId('numRecordsInput').value;

    var url = 'getItems.php?firstItem=' + firstIndex + '&numItems=' + numItems;

    ajaxGet(url, onDataReceived, function(){alert('ajax failed! :(');} )
}

/*
<div class="four_images">
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.11" id="alt1" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt1"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter]; ?>"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-item">
            <input type="radio" name="image" value="7.12" id="alt2" class="hidden">
            <label for="alt2"><img src="images/<?php echo $data[$counter+1] ?>"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
*/
function onDataReceived(ajax)
{
    var rawData = ajax.response;
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);

    var div = newEl('div');
    div.className = 'four_images';

    forEach(parsedData, makeItem);
    byId('myForm').innerHTML = '';
    byId('myForm').appendChild(div);

    function makeItem(dataItem, index, arrayOfItems)
    {
        var itemDiv = newEl('div');
        itemDiv.className = 'flex-item';

        var input = newEl('input');
        input.type = 'radio';
        input.name = 'image';
        input.value = 'putSomethingUsefulHere';
        input.id = "alt" + (index+1);
        input.className = 'hidden';

        var label = newEl('label');
        label.for = 'alt' + (index+1);

        var img = newEl('img');
        img.src = 'images/' + dataItem;
        label.appendChild(img);

        itemDiv.appendChild(input);
        itemDiv.appendChild(label);

        div.appendChild(itemDiv);
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.panel
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #eef;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='panel'>
        <label>Index of first record: <input type='number' id='firstRecordInput' value='0'/></label><br>
        <label>Number of records: <input type='number' id='numRecordsInput' value='2'/></label>
        <hr>
        <div style='text-align: center'><button id='goBtn'>Submit</button></div>
        <hr>
        <form id='myForm'>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, impressive! I'm not quite following the javascript though I'm afraid. A few questions: 1.Are you meaning to comment out the radio button images that are the ones to be changed? From what I understand, these are added by the javascript when the button is clicked? 2.What php document should the url point to? - I have a main one with html and php and a separate one for only php functions. Nothing happens when I click button, even when I've set file and url manually. The php code I have grasped and is working though :)

Comment: A pleasure, you're welcome. **(1)** There are some radio-buttons in the _javascript_ that are commented out. I forgot to delete them - there so I could see the structure of the html needed for the retrieved items. **(2)** `var url = 'getItems.php?firstItem=' + firstIndex + '&numItems=' + numItems;` needs to point to the php file (mine was in same folder) - I'll add an alternate code-block that uses the same method, but combines the php and html files.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the data you got is ajax data. So need to be $(document).on(...

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).on('click','img', function(){
    counter++;
    $("p").text(counter);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I was maybe unclear, but my question was really not how to solve the jQuery code, but if I should go for JS or PHP to implement both functionalities - or both, and how.

Comment: well then its really your choice. I would say read file using php and send to js.